# Jest test handleDropdownChange

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a react func like this:

```
handleDropdownChange(e, data){
   data && this.setState({[data.id]: data.value})
}
```

how to write a jest case for that?

Comment: Please provide minimal, complete code.

Answer (score 0):

```
const testing = render(<YourComponent/>);

fireEvent(testing.getByTestId('your dropdown test id prop'), 'event name', {id: data id, value: data value});
```

If event name of changing value is `onValueChanged`, then pass `valueChanged` as event name.